# How can create Google TTS button flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, text-to-speech

I found this [code](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_tts#-example-tab-) but I need help turning it to button
when I clicked button speech hello world.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_tts#-example-tab-

Answer (score 1):

This plugin requires Android SDK 21+, so you need to change project settings first. To do that open `android/app/build.gradle`, and change `minSdkVersion` to 21.
After that everything should work just the way it's described in the documentation and your button's click handler function may look like this:

```
FlutterTts flutterTts = new FlutterTts();
await flutterTts.speak("Hello World");
```